# Is there any video editing library available in Android

Tags: java, android, c, video-editing

I am looking for a video editing library in Android.

Editing tasks:

1. Appending video to the end of another video.
2. Adding sound track to the video.
3. Adding text on top of the video.
4. Giving effects to the video (Heat, Sepia)

Video library can be in Java or native language(C, C++).

Please let me know if anybody has worked on this as i want to make one for Android smartphones.

http://www.xuggle.com looks promising but they have developed this for desktop and server environments and not for mobiles.

thanks in advance.

Comment: check out this link: https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the source code to use video editing. Since it is not a mandatory feature, the  editing classes and JNI libs will not be available in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In ICS there are libvideoeditor, that used by standard MovieStudio. There are also JNI bindings for it.